# Request body is being printed out in the console but not the response

Tags: java, xml, maven, cucumber, rest-assured

I am trying to build a Rest API automation based on Java, RestAssured, and Cucumber. I ' trying to hit an endpoint via POST. The problem is when I am converting the response as string and when I print the response, it is printing the XML file contents but not the response. I also see the status code as 200. I'm not sure what is going wrong in here. Below is the sample snippet from my codebase.

I am trying to hit a WebService (SOAP WSDL).

```
// required imports

public class Service_Steps {

  Response xmlResponse;


    @When("I create a POST request for RCP for endpoint using XML")
    public void i_create_a_post_request_for_endpoint_using_xml() {
   
    // xml Request body
    String path = "pah_to_xml_file";

    File file = new File(path);

    xmlResponse = RestAssured.given().when().relaxedHTTPSValidation().accept(ContentType.XML).header(<headers>)
                    .body(file)
                    .post(url);
            
    String xmlResponseAsString = xmlResponse.then().extract().body().asString();
    
}
```

Not sure why I am seeing this ambiguity. Sometimes it is printing the response, and sometimes it is printing the XML file (request body) contents.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with developers I came to know that the SOAP EndPoint is sending out the responses in two different ways, randomly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   xmlResponse = RestAssured.given().log().all().when().relaxedHTTPSValidation().accept(ContentType.XML).header(<headers>)
                    .body(file)
                    .post(url)
                    .then()
                    .log().all()
                    .extract()
                    .response();
```

This will print out all the request & response stuff